# Invalid syntax error using listdir() and getcwd() in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I keep getting a syntax error when I try using listdir() and getcwd() (tested as alternative) in the following code. At the moment I am relatively new to python so some of the errors I am making are not immediately apparent to me.  I could use some help or insight as to how to get this code to work or options I can try. Here is my code.  I was not sure how to match the spacing in stackoverflow so it will not look as it does in the real code.

```
import csv

import sys

import os

import pandas as pd

from os import getcwd


print getcwd()
cvsRows = []

#removeCsvHeader.py header file for removing the top row of the csv file
#Loops through every file in the cwd 

os.makedirs('headerRemoved', exist_ok=True)

for C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\PCAN-Explorer 5\\Symbols\\Trace9.csv in os.getcwd('.'):
   if not C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\PCAN-Explorer 5\\Symbols\\Trace9.csv.endswith('.csv')
      continue                        #          continue #skip non-csv files
   print "'Removing header from ' + C:\\Users\\epenchansky\\Documents\\PCAN-Explorer 5\\Symbols\\Trace9.csv + '...'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Near the end, you've got a few long pathnames that aren't enclosed in quote marks.  None are a place where a literal pathname makes any sense anyway, given that you're trying to loop over whatever files might actually exist on the disk.  I think you want something like this:

```
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
   if not filename.endswith('.csv')
      continue                        #skip non-csv files
   print "'Removing header from ' + filename + '...'"
```

PS: `os.getcwd()` is not at all a substitute for `os.listdir()` - it gives you the name of the current directory, rather than its contents.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I will give that a try.